# Why is NodeJS not calculating the value?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get this simple console Node.js calculator to work, but it just won't return any value. Any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

```
    console.log(process.argv);
var x = 0;
if (process.argv[4]==="+"||process.argv[4]==="plus"){x=parseInt(process.argv[3])+parseInt(process.argv[5])}
if (process.argv[4]==="-"||process.argv[4]==="minus"){x=parseInt(process.argv[3])-parseInt(process.argv[5])}
if (process.argv[4]==="*"||process.argv[4]==="times"){x=parseInt(process.argv[3])*parseInt(process.argv[5])}
if (process.argv[4]==="/"||process.argv[4]==="over"){x=parseInt(process.argv[3])/parseInt(process.argv[5])}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array indexing on Javascript starts from 0 and not 1. Also it is best to handle divide by zero condition.

```
console.log(process.argv);
var x = 0;
if (process.argv[3] === "+" || process.argv[3] === "plus") {
  x = parseInt(process.argv[2]) + parseInt(process.argv[4]);
}
if (process.argv[3] === "-" || process.argv[3] === "minus") {
  x = parseInt(process.argv[2]) - parseInt(process.argv[4]);
}
if (process.argv[3] === "*" || process.argv[3] === "times") {
  x = parseInt(process.argv[2]) * parseInt(process.argv[4]);
}
if (process.argv[3] === "/" || process.argv[3] === "over") {
  x = parseInt(process.argv[2]) / parseInt(process.argv[4]);
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have thought about it!

Comment: @OlegArsyonov, did this solve your problem? If yes, kindly accept the answer. Else, state what else or more is needed.

Comment: @OlegArsyonov instead of all if statements, use if, else if ..... that will be a little more efficient.